# What exactly was "liked" in my web app?

Tags: facebook, magento, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook like buttons in my web app (magento store). I made a facebook app and sucessfuly connected it to the store with OpenGraph.

My opengraph shows me the likes per day stats, how many referrals from stories created, etc. But I'd like to know exactly which product was liked. And which products are the most "liked".

Is there a way for me to see something like that within facebook opengraph?

Comment: Which page is "liked" depends on the URL of your Like button.

Comment: There are hundreds of Like Buttons (one in each product page), I need to know which ones are pressed the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change google url to yours and Call this for every product url.

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='htp://google.com'&format=json
```